# Count how many dates in a column fall between 2 days

Tags: excel

I have a column with dates.

```
P1
8/24/2017
8/26/2017
8/26/2017
8/28/2017
9/14/2016
9/16/2017
8/18/2017
9/16/2017
9/13/2017
9/13/2017
8/22/2017
8/25/2017
8/23/2017
```

I'd like to know how many of these dates fall between the 1st of the month and the 10th, how many between the 11th and the 20th, and how many between then 21th  and the last day of the month. In this example the result would be:

```
1-10  0
11-20  6
21-31  7
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by adding a column Q where I extract the day from each date (=DAY(P2)), and then 3 cells that use countifs as such
=COUNTIFS(Q2:Q56,">=1",Q2:Q56,"<=10"). 
Is there a way to do it without the Q column?

Comment: please check this link https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-between-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in range `A1:A13` then use following formulas

*For 1 - 10* `=SUMPRODUCT((DAY($A$1:$A$13)>0)*(DAY($A$1:$A$13)<11))`

*For 11- 20* `=SUMPRODUCT((DAY($A$1:$A$13)>10)*(DAY($A$1:$A$13)<21))`

*For 21 - 31* `=SUMPRODUCT((DAY($A$1:$A$13)>20)*(DAY($A$1:$A$13)<32))`

See image for reference.

[image]